# Formula to map a variable to another?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

For example, I have a variable $x$ that contains the value $100$, and assume I also have a variable $y$ that contains the value $300$ is there a method to decrement $x$ by some amount and have $y$ be lowered by an amount proportional to $y$ so that when $x = 0$, $y = 0$

I brute forced this crude method, I'm wondering if there is a better way.
$x * 200 / 176 = y$ so when I subract from $x$, $y$ is subtracted a proportionate amount.

Comment: How about $3(100-x)=(300-y)$ that is $y=3x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. What you need to do to get both $x$ and $y$ to $0$ is subtract $100$ from $x$ and subtract $300$ from $y$. The ratio between the two is $\frac {100}{300} = \frac 1 3$. In other words, for every $1$ unit you remove from $x$, you need to remove $3$ from $y$. Then you can get both to equal $0$ after $100$ subtractions (decrements).

You can then adjust this to the size of your decrement for one of the variables. Suppose you want to remove $0.5$ from $x$ on every decrement. Then you need to remove $3 \cdot 0.5 = 1.5$ from every $y$ decrement.

Comment: I'm not sure how to square his brute-force solution of "$x * 200/176 = y$" (not exactly sure what that means, either) with your simple solution.

Comment: @BrianTung I was totally unsure what OP meant with his crude method, so I disregarded it.

Comment: I guess I'll have to be careful with how I ask my questions then. :-P

Comment: By "brute-force method" I meant I just tried out different operators until I got a desired result. I'm not too familiar with mathematical terminology, your solution looks nice and elegant, mind telling me if I used the word "map" correctly in this question?

Comment: @R1v2 your use of the word `map` was correct in some very technical sense, but was basically a poor choice in this context. I would call your question "How to proportionally decrement variables?"

Comment: @R1v2 I would generally recommend looking up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29